# Why do I get "This user account does not exist" in Magento admin panel

Tags: magento

I am logged in the admin panel from Magento and all the time I change the page (surfing trough Magento admin panel), I get this error message

**This user account does not exist**

I've removed my account and recreate it and I have the same problem. I think that there can be something wrong in the DB but I do not know what is wrong there. It is not affecting the website admin, I think, but is frustrating to see that all the time there.

Did someone had the same problem like me?

---

I've found something in Zend lib and now is not there anymore. I am waiting for some time and then I can post the solution.

Comment: You tried signing out and back in again?

Comment: Yes. I was forced to do this when I've delete the account and recreate it

Comment: Please delete your cookies and var/session and try again

Comment: Tried that and is the same problem.